# Cannot convert value "" to type "System.Char"

Tags: csv, powershell, csv-import

Hi I tried to create a PS script to Assign Drive letter,Format and Label the Drive with required Allocation Unit Size.

CSV file(Storage_Data_Input.txt) is like:

```
DiskNumber,DriveLetter,NewFileSystemLabel,AllocationUnitSize
7,N,Drive_N,4096
7,N,Drive_N,4096
```

The script goes like this:

```
########################
# New Partition/Drive letter/Format/Label/Allocation
Measure-Command{ 

Clear


$Datalist = Import-Csv "H:\My Documents\My Powershell\Storage_Data_Input.txt"
$ServerList = Get-Content "H:\My Documents\My Powershell\serverlist.txt"

ForEach ($Item in $Datalist){
$DiskNumber=$($Item.DiskNumber)
$driveletter=$($Item.DriveLetter)
$NewFileSystemLabel=$($Item.NewFileSystemLabel)
$AllocationUnitSize=$($Item.AllocationUnitSize)


$c=Get-Credential Domain\Userid 

foreach ($ServerName in $ServerList){
Write-Host "Setting Drive_"$DriveLetter" on server "$ServerName""
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $ServerName -Credential $c -ScriptBlock {

Stop-Service -Name ShellHWDetection

New-Partition -DiskNumber "$DiskNumber" -UseMaximumSize -DriveLetter "$driveletter" | Format-Volume -FileSystem NTFS -NewFileSystemLabel "$NewFileSystemLabel" -AllocationUnitSize "$AllocationUnitSize" -Force -Confirm:$false

Start-Service -Name ShellHWDetection 

}}}}
```

Getting the following ERROR when executing:

```
Cannot process argument transformation on parameter 'DriveLetter'. Cannot convert value "" to type "System.Char". Error: "String must be exactly one character long."
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [New-Partition], ParameterBindin...mationException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentTransformationError,New-Partition
+ PSComputerName        : Servername
```

Comment: i havent tested this but i think in your CSV the driveletter column should just contain the drive letter "N" instead of "Drive_N"

Answer (score 3):

If you're executing remotely variables must either by passed as an argument list or referenced using the "using" provider.

e.g.

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $ServerName -Credential $c -ScriptBlock {
    Stop-Service -Name ShellHWDetection
    New-Partition -DiskNumber "$using:DiskNumber" -UseMaximumSize -DriveLetter "$using:driveletter" | Format-Volume -FileSystem NTFS -NewFileSystemLabel "$using:NewFileSystemLabel" -AllocationUnitSize "$using:AllocationUnitSize" -Force -Confirm:$false
    Start-Service -Name ShellHWDetection 
}
```

Comment: Hi Chris, Thank you so very much. I was able to run the script without errors.